# Recursive directory creation for Node.js 0.5.x

Tags: windows, node.js, file-io

I have a function that downloads a file and saves it in a nested directory structure based on parameters sent to it (ex: ./somedir/a/b/c or ./somedir2/a/d/b). I cannot trust that any directory along the way has been created so I need to have each directory along the filepath checked and created if it doesn't exist. Now, I have some code that works perfectly for Node 0.4.x, but something has broken in at least the Windows version of Node 0.5.x (tested on 0.5.10 specifically).

I am terrible with understanding filesystems, so if someone could figure out how I could make this work or replace it with something else that works similarly, I would very much appreciate it. The goal is to have code that would function properly on both Unix and Windows as well as Node 0.4.x and 0.5.x.

```
// automatically create directories if they do not exist at a path
function mkdirs(_path, mode, callback) {
  var dirs = _path.split("/");
  var walker = [dirs.shift()];

  var walk = function (ds, acc, m, cb) {
    if (ds.length > 0) {
      var d = ds.shift();
      acc.push(d);
      var dir = acc.join("/");

      fs.stat(dir, function (err, stat) {
        if (err) {
          // file does not exist
          if (err.errno == 2) {
            fs.mkdir(dir, m, function (erro) {
              if (erro && erro.errno != 17) {
                terminal.error(erro, "Failed to make " + dir);
                return cb(new Error("Failed to make " + dir + "\n" + erro));
              } else {
                return walk(ds, acc, m, cb);
              }
            });
          } else {
            return cb(err);
          }
        } else {
          if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            return walk(ds, acc, m, cb);
          } else {
            return cb(new Error("Failed to mkdir " + dir + ": File exists\n"));
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      return cb();
    }
  };
  return walk(dirs, walker, mode, callback);
};
```

Example Usage:

```
mkdirs('/path/to/file/directory/', 0777, function(err){
```

EDIT: Update for Node 0.8.x (in CoffeeScript):

```
# 
# Function mkdirs
# Ensures all directories in a path exist by creating those that don't
# @params
#    path:      string of the path to create (directories only, no files!)
#    mode:      the integer permission level
#    callback:  the callback to be used when complete
# @callback
#    an error object or false
#
mkdirs = (path, mode, callback) ->
  tryDirectory = (dir, cb) ->
    fs.stat dir, (err, stat) ->
      if err #the file doesn't exist, try one stage earlier then create
        if err.errno is 2 or err.errno is 32 or err.errno is 34
          if dir.lastIndexOf("/") is dir.indexOf("/") #only slash remaining is initial slash
            #should only be triggered when path is '/' in Unix, or 'C:/' in Windows
            cb new Error("notfound")
          else
            tryDirectory dir.substr(0, dir.lastIndexOf("/")), (err) ->
              if err #error, return
                cb err
              else #make this directory
                fs.mkdir dir, mode, (error) ->
                  if error and error.errno isnt 17
                    cb new Error("failed")
                  else
                    cb()
        else #unkown error
          cb err
      else
        if stat.isDirectory() #directory exists, no need to check previous directories
          cb()
        else #file exists at location, cannot make folder
          cb new Error("exists")
  path = (if path.indexOf("\\") >= 0 then path.replace("\\", "/") else path) #change windows slashes to unix
  path = path.substr(0, path.length - 1)  if path.substr(path.length - 1) is "/" #remove trailing slash
  tryDirectory path, callback
```

Comment: I have tried using differing splitting logic determined if the OS is Windows `var windows = _path.indexOf('\\') >= 0;`, but I am still getting ENOENT errors. From what I can tell, fs.stat is returning an error with errno 32, which causes the code to fail.

Comment: After doing some more research, it appears that something is off about fs.stat, so I submitted an [issue on github](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1927).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at node-fs (https://npmjs.org/package/node-fs).

node-fs is an extension to the original nodejs fs library, offering new functionalities, such as recursive directory creation.

Comment: That's great!...the only answer here which allows the operation to be done async as far as I can see.

Comment: Y u no tell us how to do it with Node.fs?

Answer (score 12):

```
function mkdir(path, root) {

    var dirs = path.split('/'), dir = dirs.shift(), root = (root || '') + dir + '/';

    try { fs.mkdirSync(root); }
    catch (e) {
        //dir wasn't made, something went wrong
        if(!fs.statSync(root).isDirectory()) throw new Error(e);
    }

    return !dirs.length || mkdir(dirs.join('/'), root);
}
```

usage:

```
var fs = require('fs');
mkdir('parent/child/grandchild');
```

Comment: This worked great for me, however I had to change the hard-coded UNIX path separators with Node's cross-platform path separator constant. Rather than modify the answer, I've created a gist for it https://gist.github.com/3960169

Comment: Nice, but a shame it's synchronous

Answer (score 5):

I have a website which allows users upload their photo into their own folder. I could not find a good open source module to create directories recursively, so I implemented one. https://github.com/samxxu/ensureDir，which can be installed by

```
$ npm install ensureDir
```

Here is the full source code:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

/**
 * ensure a directory exists, create it recursively if not.
 *
 * @param dir The directory you want to ensure it exists
 * @param mode Refer to fs.mkdir()
 * @param callback
 */
module.exports = function ensureDir(dir, mode, callback) {
  if (mode && typeof mode === 'function') {
    callback = mode;
    mode = null;
  }

  mode = mode || 0777 & (~process.umask());

  callback = callback || function () {
  };

  _ensureDir(dir, mode, callback);
}

function _ensureDir(dir, mode, callback) {
  var existsFunction = fs.exists || path.exists;

  existsFunction(dir, function (exists) {
    if (exists) return callback(null);

    var current = path.resolve(dir);
    var parent = path.dirname(current);

    _ensureDir(parent, mode, function (err) {
      if (err) return callback(err);

      fs.mkdir(current, mode, function (err) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the most efficient, async version. It works top-down so that no unnecessary exist calls are made from the bottom-up. (i.e.: makes the minimal amount of system calls).

Answer (score 1):

make a synchronous version base on geoffreak's.

thanks for geoffreak.

```
function mkdirs(path, mode, callback){
    var path = path.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? path.replace(/\\/g, '/') : path;//change windows slashes to unix
    if (path.substr(path.length - 1) == '/') { //remove trailing slash
        path = path.substr(0, path.length - 1);
    }  
    console.log('path is:' + path );

    function tryDirectory(dir, cb){
        console.log('path is:' + dir );
        var stat ;
        try {
            stat = fs.statSync(dir) ;

            // the file exist
            if (stat.isDirectory()) { //directory exists, no need to check previous directories
                cb();
            }
            else { //file exists at location, cannot make folder
                return cb(new Error('exists'));
            }

        } 
        catch(err) 
        {
            if (err) { //the file doesn't exist, try one stage earlier then create
                console.log('failed to get stat of ' + dir + ', errno is :' + err.errno);
                if (err.errno == 2 || err.errno == 32 || err.errno == 34 ) {

                    //if (dir.lastIndexOf('/') == dir.indexOf('/')) {//only slash remaining is initial slash
                        //should only be triggered when path is '/' in Unix, or 'C:/' in Windows
                        //cb(new Error('notfound'));
                    //}
                    if (dir.length < 2) {
                        cb(new Error('invalid_path'));
                    }
                    else {
                        // try one stage earlier then create 
                        tryDirectory(dir.substr(0, dir.lastIndexOf('/')), function(err){
                            if (err) { //error, return
                                cb(err);
                            }
                            else { //make this directory
                                try {
                                    fs.mkdirSync(dir, mode);

                                    console.log('make dir ok, dir:' + dir);
                                    cb();                                
                                }
                                catch (error) {
                                    if (error && error.errno != 17 ) {
                                        console.log("Failed to make " + dir);
                                        return cb(new Error('failed'));
                                    } 
                                }                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else { //unkown error
                    console.log(util.inspect(err, true));
                    cb(err);
                }
            }

        }

    }
    tryDirectory(path, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Also this works. Iterative, non-recursive, algo.

```

```
function mkdirs(path) {
    var dirs = path.split('/');
    var prevDir = dirs.splice(0,1)+"/";
    while(dirs.length > 0) {
        var curDir = prevDir + dirs.splice(0,1);
        if (! fs.existsSync(curDir) ) {
            fs.mkdirSync(curDir);
        }
        prevDir = curDir + '/';
    }
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

It feels rather silly answering my own question, but I seem to have it figured out. Just make sure you use relative paths based off of __dirname to ensure cross-platform compatibility. If anyone spots any issues with this please let me know. I have tested it on Windows (0.5.10) and Mac (0.4.12).

```
// automatically create directories if they do not exist at a path
function mkdirs(path, mode, callback){
    var path = path.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? path.replace('\\', '/') : path;//change windows slashes to unix
    if (path.substr(path.length - 1) == '/') { //remove trailing slash
        path = path.substr(0, path.length - 1);
    }
    function tryDirectory(dir, cb){
        fs.stat(dir, function (err, stat) {
            if (err) { //the file doesn't exist, try one stage earlier then create
                if (err.errno == 2 || err.errno == 32) {
                    if (dir.lastIndexOf('/') == dir.indexOf('/')) {//only slash remaining is initial slash
                        //should only be triggered when path is '/' in Unix, or 'C:/' in Windows
                        cb(new Error('notfound'));
                    }
                    else {
                        tryDirectory(dir.substr(0, dir.lastIndexOf('/')), function(err){
                            if (err) { //error, return
                                cb(err);
                            }
                            else { //make this directory
                                fs.mkdir(dir, mode, function (error) {
                                    if (error && error.errno != 17) {
                                        console.log("Failed to make " + dir);
                                        return cb(new Error('failed'));
                                    } else {
                                        cb();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else { //unkown error
                    console.log(util.inspect(err, true));
                    cb(err);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (stat.isDirectory()) { //directory exists, no need to check previous directories
                    cb();
                }
                else { //file exists at location, cannot make folder
                    return cb(new Error('exists'));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    tryDirectory(path, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to have a really small version of this for a deployment server this is about as pretty as I could get it.

```
function mkdirs(file){
    var dirs, paths=[];
    dirs = file.split('/');
    while(dirs.length>1){
        paths.push(dirs.shift());
        var tmp = paths.join('/');
        if(!fs.existsSync('/'+tmp )) fs.mkdirSync('/'+tmp);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`# npm install -g node-fs`

**coffeeScript code**:

```
String::dirReAdd = -> 
    require('node-fs').mkdirSync(@.toString(), 0o777, true)
    @

# './tmp2/example_sync/first/second/third/fourth/fifth/'.dirReAdd().pr()
```